# Convolutional Neural Network not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a Convolutional Neural Network for image recognition on a training set 1500 images with 15 categories. I've been told that, with this architecture and initial weights drawn from a Gaussian distribution with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 0.01 and the initial bias values to 0, with the proper learning rate it should achieve an accuracy of around 30%.

However, it doesn't learn anything at all: the accuracy is similar to the one of a random classifier and the weights after training still follow a normal distribution. What am I doing wrong?

This is the NN

```
class simpleCNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(simpleCNN,self).__init__() #initialize the model

    self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,out_channels=8,kernel_size=3,stride=1) #Output image size is (size+2*padding-kernel)/stride -->62*62
    self.relu1=nn.ReLU()
    self.maxpool1=nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2) #outtput image 62/2-->31*31

    self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8,out_channels=16,kernel_size=3,stride=1) #output image is 29*29
    self.relu2=nn.ReLU()
    self.maxpool2=nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2) #output image is 29/2-->14*14  (MaxPool2d approximates size with floor)

    self.conv3=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=1) #output image is 12*12
    self.relu3=nn.ReLU()

    self.fc1=nn.Linear(32*12*12,15) #16 channels * 16*16 image (64*64 with 2 maxpooling of stride 2), 15 output features=15 classes
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

  def forward(self,x):
    x=self.conv1(x)
    x=self.relu1(x)
    x=self.maxpool1(x)

    x=self.conv2(x)
    x=self.relu2(x)
    x=self.maxpool2(x)

    x=self.conv3(x)
    x=self.relu3(x)

    x=x.view(-1,32*12*12)

    x=self.fc1(x)
    x=self.softmax(x)

    return x
```

The inizialization:

```
def init_weights(m):
  if isinstance(m,nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m,nn.Linear):
    nn.init.normal_(m.weight,0,0.01)
    nn.init.zeros_(m.bias)

model = simpleCNN()
model.apply(init_weights)
```

The training function:

```
loss_function=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer=optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.1,momentum=0.9)

def train_one_epoch(epoch_index,loader):
  running_loss=0

  for i, data in enumerate(loader):

    inputs,labels=data #get the minibatch
    outputs=model(inputs) #forward pass

    loss=loss_function(outputs,labels) #compute loss
    running_loss+=loss.item() #sum up the loss for the minibatches processed so far

    optimizer.zero_grad() #reset gradients
    loss.backward() #compute gradient
    optimizer.step() #update weights

  return running_loss/(i+1) # average loss per minibatch
```

The training:

```
EPOCHS=20

best_validation_loss=np.inf

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  print('EPOCH{}:'.format(epoch+1))

  model.train(True)
  train_loss=train_one_epoch(epoch,train_loader)

  running_validation_loss=0.0

  model.eval()

  with torch.no_grad(): # Disable gradient computation and reduce memory consumption
    for i,vdata in enumerate(validation_loader):
      vinputs,vlabels=vdata
      voutputs=model(vinputs)
      vloss=loss_function(voutputs,vlabels)
      running_validation_loss+=vloss.item()
  validation_loss=running_validation_loss/(i+1)
  print('LOSS train: {} validation: {}'.format(train_loss,validation_loss))

  if validation_loss<best_validation_loss: #save the model if it's the best so far
    timestamp=datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    best_validation_loss=validation_loss
    model_path='model_{}_{}'.format(timestamp,epoch)
    torch.save(model.state_dict(),model_path)
```

With the default initializion it works a little better, but i'm supposed to reach 30% with the gaussian.
Could you spot some issue that might be causing it not to learn? I have already tries different learning rates and momentum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is given was given by the fact that I was importing the images, and then converting them to tensors with `transforms.ToTensor()`, which rescales the pixel values in the range [0,1]. While the CNN was actually meant to work with [0,255].
Having so small pixel values, a small standard deviation with the normal initialization is almost equivalent to a null initialization.
So in order to fix this kind of problem you have to be sure that the pixel values are in the range [0,255].
Also the `softmax` at the end of the network worsens the problem, as already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use your model to attain about 90% validation accuracy on an MNIST dataset (1500 samples, 10 classes). I used the same network you defined, but modified the layer sizes for my image dimensions and output classes (28x28 grayscale input, 10-class output).

Main things I did:

- Normalised the input images
- Used the default layer initialisations
- Used an Adam optimizer rather than SGD
- **Update:** Don't return `softmax` because the loss function needs the raw logits

[image]

[image]

```
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import torchvision

from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
torch.manual_seed(0)

#Load data
mnist = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./torch_mnist', train=True, download=True)

#Get tensors, and to appropriate dtypes
X = mnist.data.float()
y = mnist.targets.long()

#Normalise X
means = X.mean(dim=0)
stds = X.std(dim=0)
X = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(means, stds + 1e-10)(X)
X = torch.unsqueeze(X, dim=1)

#Shuffle. Stratified sampling of 1500 samples.
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, _, y, _ = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, train_size=1500, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

class simpleCNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
    self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
    self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
    self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
    self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()

    # self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 12 * 12, 15)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 3 * 3, 10)
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

  def forward(self,x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.relu1(x)
    x = self.maxpool1(x)

    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.relu2(x)
    x = self.maxpool2(x)

    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.relu3(x)

    # x = x.view(-1, 32 * 12 * 12)
    x = x.view(-1, 32 * 3 * 3)

    x = self.fc1(x) #return raw logits to CE loss function
    #x = self.softmax(x)

    return x

def init_weights(m):
  if isinstance(m,nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m,nn.Linear):
    nn.init.normal_(m.weight,0,0.01)
    nn.init.zeros_(m.bias)

model = simpleCNN()
# model.apply(init_weights)

loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

validation_size = 250
train_loader = DataLoader(list(zip(X[:-validation_size], y[:-validation_size])), shuffle=True, batch_size=32)
validation_loader = DataLoader(list(zip(X[-validation_size:], y[-validation_size:])), batch_size=validation_size)

def train_one_epoch(epoch_index, loader):
  running_loss = 0

  for i, data in enumerate(loader):

    inputs, labels = data #get the minibatch
    outputs = model(inputs) #forward pass

    loss = loss_function(outputs, labels) #compute loss
    running_loss += loss.item() #sum up the loss for the minibatches processed so far

    optimizer.zero_grad() #reset gradients
    loss.backward() #compute gradient
    optimizer.step() #update weights

  return running_loss / (i + 1) # average loss per minibatch

EPOCHS = 16

best_validation_loss = np.inf

train_losses = []
validation_losses = []
validation_accuracies = []

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print('EPOCH{:>2d}'.format(epoch + 1), end='    ')

    model.train()
    train_loss = train_one_epoch(epoch, train_loader)
    
    running_validation_loss = 0.0

    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        total_correct = 0
        for i, vdata in enumerate(validation_loader):
            vinputs, vlabels = vdata
            voutputs = model(vinputs)
            vloss = loss_function(voutputs, vlabels)
            running_validation_loss += vloss.item()
            
            total_correct += (voutputs.argmax(dim=1) == vlabels).sum()
    validation_loss = running_validation_loss / (i + 1)
    validation_acc = total_correct / len(validation_loader.dataset) * 100
    print('LOSS train: {:1.3f} validation: {:1.3f} | ACC val: {:>5.1f}%'.format(
        train_loss, validation_loss, validation_acc
    ))
  
    if validation_loss < best_validation_loss: #save the model if it's the best so far
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
        best_validation_loss = validation_loss
        model_path = 'model_{}_{}'.format(timestamp, epoch)
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_path)
    
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    validation_losses.append(validation_loss)
    validation_accuracies.append(validation_acc)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(train_losses, color='tab:red', linewidth=3, label='train loss')
plt.plot(validation_losses, color='tab:green', linewidth=3, label='validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('CE loss')

ax_right = plt.gca().twinx()
ax_right.plot(validation_accuracies, color='tab:green', linestyle='--', label='validation accuracy')
ax_right.set_ylabel('accuracy (%)')

plt.gcf().legend(ncol=3)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Using the default initialization and Adam's optimizer (without normalizing the input) i was able to reach 23% , which is closer to my expectations; however it's really weird because SGD and Gaussian initialization should work fine, or at least not that bad. Do you have any idea of why this happening?

Comment: You're welcome. I ran it again, this time with no input normalisation, using SGD, and your `normal_` weight initialisation, and got at validation accuracy of 75% at epoch 25 (it improves with more epochs). The main thing I did was reduce the SGD learning rate down to 1e-3 (momentum=0.9), so I think the primary issue was that the learning rate was too high initially. If you want to use normal initialisation, consider looking into `kaiming_normal_` - it's similar to what you're using but it adjusts the variance based on input or output size of the layer.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your result on MNIST, but on my dataset it's still very bad, I've tried many different learning rates (going down to 1e-8, the best one turned out to be 1e-5) May there be some kind of problem with the way i have loaded the dataset? I really can't figure out, if you could give a look it wiould be a great help

Comment: `!wget -c https://github.com/AlessandroCesaTs/Computer_Vision_Project_Cesa/archive/main.zip
!unzip main.zip
train_path = "Computer_Vision_Project_Cesa-main/CVPR2023_project_2_and_3_data/train"
test_path = "Computer_Vision_Project_Cesa-main/CVPR2023_project_2_and_3_data/test"
transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((64,64)),transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Grayscale()])
train=ImageFolder(root=train_path,transform=transform)
test=ImageFolder(root=test_path,transform=transform)
#split training set into training and validation
train_size=int(0.85*len(train))`

Comment: `validation_size=len(train)-train_size
training_set,validation_set=torch.utils.data.random_split(train,[train_size,validation_size])
batch_size = 32
train_loader = DataLoader(training_set, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
validation_loader = DataLoader(validation_set, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)
`

Comment: The model shouldn't return `softmax` - just return the result from the line before as `CrossEntropyLoss` needs the raw logits. `NAdam` rather than SGD helped a lot. When I used `init_weights()` the model didn't learn. This could be for two reasons: different layer types (linear, conv) benefit from different initialisation schemes, and furthermore the initialisation statistics ought to be adjusted for layer size. `init_weights()` doesn't do either. However, I found that simply replacing `normal_` with `kaiming_normal_` worked okay, if you don't want to use the defaults.

Comment: Thank you; I was able to reach 30% (which is what i needed for this model) with `kaiming_normal_`, i will try to investigate further why `init_normal_` works so bad

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to progress with the model. One of the differences between `kaiming_normal_` and `normal_` is that kaiming chooses an std based on layer dimensions ("fan_in" or "fan_out"), whereas `normal_` is just a fixed constant.

Comment: I was able to find the solution, the problem was exactly on the std